# Programmatically create ODBC Data Source using the IBM SPSS 20 standalone Data File Driver

Tags: python, vba, odbc, spss

**The problem:**

I have a .sav file containing a lot of data from a questionnaire. This data is transferred to an access database through an ODBC connection using VBA. The VBA macro is being used by a lot of not so tech-savvy coworkers and each time they need to use a new .sav file, they need to create or alter a connection. It can be a hastle to explain how every time, so I would like to be able to create this connection programmatically (ideally contained in the VBA macro, but if that's not possible something like a python script will do).

**The solution I thought of:**

I'm not very familiar with VBA, so to begin with I tried doing it with python. I found this example, which seemed (to me) like a solution:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/414879-create-an-odbc-data-source/

However, I'm not sure what arguments to feed SQLConfigDataSource. I tried:

```
create_sys_dsn(
    'IBM SPSS Statistics 20 Data File Driver - Standalone',
    SDSN='SAVDB',
    HST='C:\ProgramFiles\IBM\SPSS\StatisticsDataFileDriver\20\Standalone\cfg\oadm.ini',
    PRT='StatisticsSAVDriverStandalone',
    CP_CONNECT_STRING='data/Dustin_w44-47_2011.sav',
    CP_UserMissingIsNull=1)
```

But to no avail.

Being green in this field, I realise that my proposed solution might not even be the correct one. Does stackoverflow have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you prompt the user for the location of the file, and build the connection string from that? that way, you don't need to venture outside of vba.

Comment: Well, the user is required to have the .sav file in a specific directory. Does that help me? Otherwise, if it can be done with VBA then it is, presumably, no problem that the user is prompted for the file location.

Comment: Not related to the question. But found the solution I needed via the link you pasted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that happens to need a solution for this, what I ended up doing was creating the system DSN by manually editing the registry.

To see which keys and values needs to be modified, create a system DSN manually and inspect the values in 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI[DSN]' and 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources'. It should be fairly clear how to create a DSN through VBA then.

Answer (score 0):

once you have the filename, from a prompt such as

```
dim fd as Object
dim CSVFilename as String
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(3)
'Use a With...End With block to reference the FileDialog object.
With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Add "Data Files", "*.csv", 1
    .ButtonName = "Forecast"
    If .Show = -1 Then
        CSVFilename = .SelectedItems(1) 
        ' returns an array, even with multiselect off
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With
'Set the object variable to Nothing.
Set fd = Nothing
```

then you should be able to construct the connection string, which will allow you to open the file

```
Dim MyConnect as new Connection

With MyConnect
    .Provider="IBM SPSS Statistics 20 Data File Driver - Standalone"
    .ConnectionString="data/" & CSVFilename
    .Open
End With
```

I would also point out that if you can import the **csv** file using the `External Data -> Text File` (or equivalent), then a command more like

```
DoCmd.TransferText(TransferType, SpecificationName, TableName, FileName, _
    HasFieldNames, HTMLTableName, CodePage)
```

would probably work out easier for you

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. I will try it out when I get into work tomorrow!